# Enviar notificaciones cuando se inserte a MySQL desde Asterisk

Tags: mysql, nodejs, websocket

Deseo saber cómo enviar una **notificación** luego de haberse hecho una inserción en MySQL. Tenemos un sistema que usa Asterisk para registrar llamadas telefónicas de nuestro Call Center. El tema es que usando Nodejs y Socketio queremos notificar de las inserciones a modo de reporte a un usuario específico.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Facil, con un AGI (*[Asterisk Gateway Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk_Gateway_Interface)*). Más información en:
[Asterisk Project ➡️ Home ➡️ Configuration ➡️ Interfaces](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=32375589)

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo hecho de la siguiente manera, espero lo puedas adaptar con Nodejs.

Debes utilizar:

1- Trigger en MySQL, Trigger es un disparador que se ejecuta cada vez que algo ocurre en una tabla ya sea insertando, actualizando o borrando registros, aprovechando esta propiedad de MySQL entonces creas un trigger para que cada vez que se inserta un registro en la tabla que es de tu interés también se cree un registro en una tabla nueva con los campos que tu desees incluyendo fecha y hora, por ejemplo el siguiente código crea un trigger que  se desencadena cada vez que se actualiza un registro en la tabla employees creando otro registro en la tabla employees_audit

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_employee_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO employees_audit
SET action = 'update',
 employeeNumber = OLD.employeeNumber,
    lastname = OLD.lastname,
    changedat = NOW(); 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

2- Para notificar al usuario que hubo una inserción puedes utilizar Nodej, PHP o algun lenguaje similar, yo te recomiendo algo simple como crear una pagina HTML que tenga siempre abierta el usuario y a través de AJAX se actualice sola, si no conoces AJAX entonces coloca un botón en la página para que el usuario refresque en forma manual.

3- Si quieres algo más avanzado puedes enlazar Nodej (si lo permite) o PHP con AGI de Asterisk (Asterisk Gateway Interface ) el AGI se comunica con otros lenguajes de programación para que utilices toda la potencialidad telefónica de Asterisk ya sea notificando a los teléfonos IP o bien generando llamadas, sobre AGI enontraras toda la informacion y ejemplos en https://www.voip-info.org/wiki-Asterisk+AGI.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Hola para obtener los eventos del CDR usando nodejs efectivamente debes usar alguna librería de las tantas que ya proporcionan.

Puedes revisar en el siguiente repositorio tengo el uso de una de estas librerías: https://github.com/alancornejo/sockets_dashboard, en este caso uso asterisk.io.

La documentacion oficial del asterisk tambien indica la forma de capturar el evento con AMI dale una revisado a la wiki.asterisk.org "Asterisk -
 ManagerEvent_CDR"

Otras de las librerías que recomiendo es asterisk-manager, con esto también puede capturar los Eventos con nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

1.- nodejs: hay una libreria en la cual te conectas al ami, y ahi puedes ver el flujo de toda la llamada, desde que entra , que variables trae, quien la contesta, si esta en una cola, todo lo puedes ver, ahi pudieras lanzar tu notificacion que necesitas.
 
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/asterisk.io][1]

2.- agi, con esta estas un poco limitado, hay que averiguar en que momento quieres la notificacion cuando contesta el usuario o cuando culega, entonces lanzas un agi, como ya lo comento user20930